# URL asking username and password in ssrs2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

i developed one report in ssrs 2008 and then deployed it , after that i sent URL to others for checking purpose.

but whenever other colleges are using my URL then it is asking username and password to them.

how can i overcome this issue.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

as this report is in your ssrs, the other users must enter your credential to access it... there is no way you can overcome it.

Comment: Azzy , actually the URL should not ask username and password.i know it but i am not able to implement it i.e url should not ask username and password

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your ReportServer needs to be [setup with Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to allow users of your intranet to access the reports using their own credentials. If the users are external to your network, then maybe look at the [other options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (basic, forms etc) available for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set this property in order to turn off  prompting for server login   EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False"

Comment: Suhas where can i find EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False"